# How do I convert a UILabel to a string?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to cast a UILabel to a string, but it always fails. How else would I cast it? `friendname` is a UILabel, and `friendusername` is a string.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "friendsSongs"){

        let nextViewOBJ = segue.destinationViewController as! FriendsMusic
        nextViewOBJ.friendusername = friendname as! String
    }
}
```

Comment: Start by reviewing the documentation for `UILabel`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [`text`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/text) attribute on UILabel:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "friendsSongs"){

        let nextViewOBJ = segue.destinationViewController as! FriendsMusic
        nextViewOBJ.friendusername = friendname.text
    }
}
```

You can't cast a UILabel to a String - but you can find what the text *of* a UILabel is. That's what you want to do here.

Answer (score 4):

You don't want to convert a `UILabel` to a string, you want to access its text property:

```
nextViewOBJ.friendusername = friendname.text
```